# Pass javascript variable as argument in ASP.NET MVC form

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to pass a javascript variable in an ASP.NET MVC form?

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("SetShutdownTime", "Vm"))
{
    <p id="shutdownText"></p>

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @type = "time", @step = 900, @autofocus = "autofocus" })
    //SET HERE m => m.Name = $currentName

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type='button' id='closeShutdownDialog' value='Close' />
}

<script>
    var currentName = "HelloWorld"; 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it by myself

I've just made an invisible textbox and set the value of the textbox to `currentName`. Maybe not the best solution, but it works

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible. At the begining your cshtml file is parsed by Razor, and after that scripts are running.

You can always modify elements using jQuery by accessing them via ID.